# Getting the JSON for a Google Maps Embed route

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I know that I can use the [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start) to return a json file containing the directions from point A to point B, including waypoints and alternative routes if so desired.  Doing this requires formatting a string to the specifications provided (e.g.: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New+York,NY&destination=Orlando,FL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New%20York,NY&destination=Orlando,FL)), and then sending a request:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New+York,NY&destination=Orlando,FL')
print r.json()
```

However, I was wondering if it is possible to set up a simple website that uses a [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode) (or something similar) and then somehow take the route selected on the Maps Embed API and get the json for that route?  This would allow me to select the precise route I wanted (for instance select a specific alternative route or reroute a small part of the trip by dragging the blue line).

EDIT:  To clarify based on the answer by Gugas:
When you enter an origin and destination into Google Maps, you can manually adjust the blue polyline so that it routes through a specific point (for example [Reno, NV to Yosemite Valley, CA](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Reno,+Nevada/Yosemite+Valley,+California/@38.6237169,-121.0905648,9z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x809940ae9292a09d:0x40c5c5ce7438f787!2m2!1d-119.8138027!2d39.5296329!1m5!1m1!1s0x8096f1fe38f263af:0x19213f2e54c9e26e!2m2!1d-119.5936038!2d37.7455701) results in a route that goes west of the park and then back east (because the CA 120 is closed right now), however dragging the polyline I can make the route use the [CA 120 and the east entrance to the park](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Reno,+Nevada/Yosemite+Valley,+California/@38.6237169,-121.0905648,9z/data=!4m19!4m18!1m10!1m1!1s0x809940ae9292a09d:0x40c5c5ce7438f787!2m2!1d-119.8138027!2d39.5296329!3m4!1m2!1d-119.1522156!2d37.9335258!3s0x809645e37007a211:0x1a52927b36970880!1m5!1m1!1s0x8096f1fe38f263af:0x19213f2e54c9e26e!2m2!1d-119.5936038!2d37.7455701!3e0)).

So ideally I would like to be able to enter a start and destination, modify the route by dragging the polyline if needed, and then get the directions in a JSON format as I would with a Google Maps Directions API request, and I was wondering if this is even possible to do.

Comment: So, Directions API? Maps JS API? Embed API? What do you want? Your questions is still unclear. I'd suggest you delete this question and come up with a clear one.

Comment: I want the functionality of the Directions API (that is, the JSON that is returned following a request), but I want to be able to click and drag the polyline to get a specific route before the JSON for that route is generated.  I want to know if such a thing is possible, and if so what I would need to do to accomplish that.

Comment: Be aware that you can't do everything you want with the data returned by their various APIs... Just a side note. That said, requesting directions, dragging the Polyline, you can do with the Maps API. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult should give you some information about the format.